# default_scope with where and order plus how to override it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a model of microposts and I want that every query will come with `where approved = true` and `order by creat_at desc` by default.

Now this code doesn't working

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  default_scope { where(approved: true), order('microposts.created_at DESC')}
end
```

Plus I wonder how do I bypass it? for example if I'm admin and I'm in the not approved view, I want to be able to see the unapproved posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `default_scope` should be this:

```
 default_scope { where(approved: true).order(created_at: :desc) }
```

To bypass the default scope you can use `unscoped`.

To see the `unapproved` posts, you can do:

```
Micropost.unscoped.all.where(approved: false)
```